# TableView order not correct at first but is updated when the app is relaunched?

Tags: ios, uitableview, sorting, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am using just one viewController to add a task and then display it. I am using NSFetchedResultsController for fetching from the coreData. I am also using NSSortDescriptor to sort tasks according to priority.

Now here is the issue, I press a '+' button and a textview with keyboard appears. I write a task and press add. By doing that I am saving the object in the coreData. At the back there is a tableview that gets updated, however, the order is not correct. If for example the first task is say 'Task 1' and then second task say 'task 2', the 'task2' appears on the top of 'task 1', but when I relaunch the app, the task2 shows under the task1 which is what it should be.

When you add a lot of tasks with different priority levels, the priority sorting is respected but the order is all over the place within that priority. Relaunching the app fixes it.

I want the tableview to be updated correctly. What am I doing wrong? Here are some code snippets:

Inserting a new row when the data is added.

```
func controllerWillChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
    tableView.beginUpdates()
}

func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {
    switch type {

    case .delete:
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .fade)
    case .insert:
        tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath as! IndexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)

    default:
        return

    }
}

func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
    tableView.endUpdates()

}
```

Notice 'Low 7' is in the blue priority area but not under 'Low 6'. It gets there when I relaunch the app

In the second pic, medium 6,7,8 all above. Relaunching the app will bring them under medium 5.

[image]
[image]

Comment: you try https://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller

Comment: such a useful comment thanks!

Comment: What are the possible values of the priority attribute, and how do they relate to the label eg “medium 1”?

Comment: @pbasdf I have a collectionViewController that has 4 cells. When u tap a cell and a particular number gets assigned to a variable (NSManagedObject). For eg, low = 1, med = 2, high = 3, urgent = 4. So when u write medium 1 and tap medium cell from cv and press done, the number 2 is assigned to a nsmanagedobject which i use to sort the data is a descending order!!

Comment: So in the cell with label “Medium 6”, for example, where does the 6 come from?

Comment: Thats just me adding a new task “medium 6”.

Comment: So, is your problem that the FRC is correctly honouring the priority sort descriptor, but not sorting within those results?

Comment: Exactly.... and when I relaunch the app the sorting is corrected!! What is the issue here?

Comment: If items have the same value for priority, the order in which they appear is undefined, unless you add a second sort descriptor.  If they appear in the correct order when you restart the app, that’s good fortune but not guaranteed.  If you provide a second sort descriptor (using that title as the key), the FRC should display them in the right place.

Comment: The thing with this is that the title can be anything you want. I believe using the time when it was added can be a good sorting key? What do u think?

Comment: Sure, the date/time when the object was added should work fine.

Comment: thanks for the help! :) Will test it out right now!